# getGeneratedKeys in EJB

Tags: java, ejb-3.1

I want to get the id of persisted object. I am using EJB 3.1.

I were using prepared statement to do this and it worked perfectly.

```
ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (generatedKeys.next()) {
    myId = generatedKeys.getLong(1);
}
```

I have been searching but found nothing said how to make this work in EJB. Here is my method used to persist object to database:

```
public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    //Something to return entity's id???
}
```

The persistence provider I am using is:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public [id_type] create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    getEntityManager().flush();
    getEntityManager().refresh(entity);
    return entity.getId();
}
```